# macdeployqt fails with "ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/lib*.dylib" after install_name_tool -change

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I'm developing a Qt application on mac, using some other libraries. I've

1. run `macdeployqt` to gather all the Qt libraries into `myApp/Contents/Framworks`
2. copied other libraries listed using `otool -L myApp/Contents/MacOS/myApp` into this directory
3. used `intall_name_tool -change` to change the path to the framworks like `install_name_tool -change "/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib" "@rpath/libc++.1.dylib" ./myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp`

But when I'm trying to run `macdeployqt` again after I changed the path rules, it fails with these errors:

```
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 83.0.0, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 60165.120.1, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 101.2.0, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 866.140.1, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1173.100.2, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 750.6.0, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 30.0.0, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1738.140.1, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 959.0.1, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 110.40.3, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 48.0.0, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 377.60.2, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 74.0.0, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1353.100.2, reexport)"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "\t/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1061.141.1, reexport)"
...
```

And even if I use `macdeployqt` with other QT projects, this error still exists.

How can I use other libraries in my Qt application correctly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you on Big Sur?

Comment: Also try without the double quotes.  Should not be running macdeployqt again after qt was automatically bundled in the previous run.